# Can I create full fledged Vista win32 applications with GUI using Windows 8 OS with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, windows-8, 32bit-64bit, visual-studio-2012

Edit: Is programming Win32 applications with c++ supported on Windows 8 OS with Visual Studio 11 that later this application can run on Windows Vista (or full fledged win32 applications with GUI) (and stay away from WinRT)?

I have written this question earlier like that:
Can I use visual studio 11 and PacktPub "Microsoft Visual C++ Windows Applications by Example" book to create applications (or full fledged win32 applications with GUI) (and stay away from WinRT) using Windows 8 OS that can run later on Windows Vista 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: oops, sorry, i must post this in stackoverflow maybe

Comment: maybe someone can move this question to stackoverflow if needed

Comment: If you are asking for the question to be migrated, you can flag it for moderator attention asking them to migrate. I have done this for you.

Comment: Windows 8 is Vista version 6.2

Answer (score 2):

You can- if you pay. The Express versions were neutered.

Comment: But please note that Visual Studio Professional is legally available for free to many developers (DreamSpark, WebsiteSpark).  A higher version than Express is required, paying may not be.

Comment: not correct - dreamspark for example does not allow you to create commercial applications. https://www.dreamspark.com/licensing/basic-EULA.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Some more details of the planned platform targeting here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/05/18/a-look-ahead-at-the-visual-studio-11-product-lineup-and-platform-support.aspx.

> To help you take advantage of the latest features, the default target for applications created with Visual Studio 11 will be set to .NET Framework 4.5 (for managed apps) and the VC11 toolset (for native apps). Both will allow your apps to run on Windows Vista and higher.

Comment: Vista or higher - ie. NOT XP. They really really want you to upgrade :)

Comment: And I understand that Visual Studio 11 itself will only run on Windows 7 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its possible.

Take care not to use/link to new Win8 apis/features/libraries (Msdn provides the minimum requirement for each api).

By default for your applications to run, you need to install new VC 11 runtime as well on the Win7/Vista box. But this requirement can be eliminated by creating statically linked option.